# Process can't access file cause it's used by mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#

I wrote a .dll file that creates logfiles with csv extension. The problem is, whenever it needs to create the path (cause it doesn't exist), it can't access the files to write something in it

```
void InitializePathDirectory(string dir)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
    }
}

void InitializeFileDirectory(string file)
{
    if (!File.Exists(file))
    {
        File.Create(file);
    }
}
```

The path here is

```
private string dirname = $"{path}\\Logs";
private string filename = $"{path}\\Logs\\{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")}.csv";
```

When I close an application, that uses this dll, it normally writes the time I
 closed the app into the logfile

```
public void onExit()
{
    //var a is the DateTime, when the application starts
    var b = DateTime.Now;

    string temp = Convert.ToString(b - a);
    string[] time = temp.Split('.');

    File.AppendAllText(filename, $"Time:; {time[0]}\n");
    File.AppendAllText(filename, $"Starttime:; {a.ToString("HH:mm:ss")}\n");
    File.AppendAllText(filename, $"Endtime:; {b.ToString("HH:mm:ss")}\n\n");
}
```

but I can't write anything into the file if the logfile path was created in the same run, it throws an Exception, that "mscorlib.dll" currently uses the logfile, so I can't access it

Comment: Try closing the file stream that `File.Create` returns.

Comment: `File.Create(file);` returns a file stream that you leave open.

Comment: You don't need to create a file, simply skip your 'InitializeFileDirectory' method. When you call 'File.AppendAllText' the file will automatically be created

Comment: You shot your left foot with File.Create().  A good practice for logging files is to create them early and keep them open for the life of the program.  And to use a logging library.

Answer (score 5):

Using [`File.Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_Create_System_String_) returns a filestream, which allows you to read/write to the newly created file. Without disposing/closing this stream, it will cause the file to remain open, which prevent your subsequent calls to `File.AppendAllText()`.

You have <strike>2</strike> **3** ways of handling this:

1. Enclose your call in a using block: `using (File.Create(filename)) {}`
2. Call dispose on the filestream manually: `File.Create(filename).Dispose();`
3. Don't use `File.Create()` at all. The [`File.AppendAllText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=netframework-4.7.2) method already checks to see if the file exists, and will create it if it doesn't, so the `File.Create()` is completely redudant and not necessary:

   > Opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. **If the file does not exist, this method creates a file,** writes the specified string to the file, then closes the file.

And lastly, as [@Tofik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7923862/tofik) pointed out in a now deleted answer, your call to `Directory.Exists(dir)` is also redudant. See the docs for [`Directory.CreateDirectory(dir)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_CreateDirectory_System_String_):

> Creates all directories and subdirectories in the specified path **unless they already exist.**